# Maven Tomcat Plugin Change Port

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I am trying to create a Spring MVC application and is deploying it with Maven Tomcat Plugin.
How do you change the context-path and port?
Here is the maven plugin I placed in my pom.xml:

```
        plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <server>localtomcat</server>
                <port>8081</port>
                <path>/test</path>
                <update>true</update>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I can't access my site with the path and port above. But I am able to do so by using the old context-path and 8080.

Comment: Could you post the output from Tomcat's startup?

Comment: `server` is not a configuration element. Change `server` to `hostName`

Comment: See here http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html

Comment: When I run maven tomcat:run, I get this output: [INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/spring

Comment: try with `tomcat7:run`. `tomcat:run` will use the old plugin in codehaus, with the default values as you didn't configure it.

Comment: Thank you @CédricC! That did the work! :D

Comment: Please make your comment as an answer so that I can mark it. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to add properties in your pom.xml, for example if you want to change the port number use this following tag :

```
<properties>
    <maven.tomcat.port>8081</maven.tomcat.port>
</properties>
```

[Click here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) for more tomcat plugin properties.

Comment: This did nothing, still running on 8080