# How to run two maven commands at the same time

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to run two maven/mvn commands at the same time, but it fails saying that the JDWP Transport address is in use.

I have one service running with

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

Then, when I try to run any maven command it fails.

```
mvn --version
```

or 
    mvn build

I always get

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
```

The reason is that the first maven command hold on port 8000 (tomcat is running on 8080)

How to I make maven use a different port?

After looking for answer, I found some related to debuging and try the following without luck

export MAVEN_OPTS="-`Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5035"; mvn build`

Comment: You try to debug maven two times. This does not work. The `MAVEN_OPTS` may only be in a single instance or you have to change the `address` in the `MAVEN_OPTS`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675600/maven-tomcat-plugin-change-port

Comment: "Address already in use" in combination with "...address=5035" should already give you a hint: when you run 2 processes with the same settings they both want to listen on port 5035, which can't work and which is what "adress already in use" means. That's not limited to maven, i.e. if you'd run another Java application with the same settings you'd get that problem as well. In general you probably don't want to run a normal maven build with debugging options enabled since you're probably not going to debug maven itself.

Comment: @Thomas No, the fist one use default 8000, so it try to set the second one to use a different port.

Comment: @UwePlonus Maybe I don't understand the concept of Debug here, because one is running a server, the other one is compiling, or getting the version number.

Comment: @Francisl your `MAVEN_OPTS` enable debugging of the maven process. You cannot run two maven processes in debug mode which share a port.

Comment: Ok, perfect, after an 'unset` of alI `MAVEN_*` settings, I still had the issus. To find out by reading the mvn script that it was also looking into `~/.mavenrc`. So I guess for anyone with that error. Make sure you dont have any `MAVEN_DEBUG` variable configured in your shell OR in `~/.mavenrc`. Thanks!